# Public массив в сингельтоне ?

Tags: ооп, java

у меня вопрос - нормально ли сделать Array публичным в сингельтоне, если к нему нужен доступ или сделать как то иначе ?

Comment: сингельтон - подразумевает, что в программе должна быть только 1 копия объекта, если в твоей проге это критическая область - делай одиночку

Comment: @Gorets я знаю что такое сингельтон, мне интересно если я делаю в нем массив и хочу иметь к нему доступ - я его делаю публичным или юзать что-то еще ?

Comment: мне кажется ты путаешь область видимости объекта с количеством его копий в программе

Comment: делай публичным =)

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать публичным массив? Это не нарушает концепции singletone

Comment: @Gorets мне кажется, что не путаю =)  я понимаю что объект моего класса  и соответсвенно массив будет один, я имею ввиду именно доступ к массиву..

Comment: @AlexWindHope думает как я =)

Comment: незнаю зачем) просто интерсно узнать.. не нарушит ли это принципы ООП)

Comment: =) нет, не нарушит, и природный баланс не нарушит, и на температуру воздуха влиять тоже не будет =)

Comment: @Gorets ok) а то я прям волновался - может мой код положит начало концу света))

Comment: для 2012 многовато концов намечается =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> незнаю зачем) просто интерсно узнать.. не нарушит ли это принципы ООП)

**Если *строго следовать* правилам ООП**, то нельзя. Если нужно читать снаружи какое-то свойство, то нужно сделать getter, если еще и изменять - еще и setter. И так везде.